# How to fetch values from JSON in golang

Tags: json, go

i have following piece of code which calls the yahoo finance api to get the stock values for given stock symbol.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

//Response structure
type Response struct {
    Query struct {
        Count   int    `json:"count"`
        Created string `json:"created"`
        Lang    string `json:"lang"`
        Results struct {
            Quote []struct {
                LastTradePriceOnly string `json:"LastTradePriceOnly"`
            } `json:"quote"`
        } `json:"results"`
    } `json:"query"`
}

func main() {
    var s Response
    response, err := http.Get("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20LastTradePriceOnly%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22,%22FB%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()

        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(contents), &s)
        fmt.Println(s.Query.Results.Quote)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
    }
}
```

fmt.Println(s.Query.Results.Quote) is giving me a multi value array since Quote is a array of structure. For eg: [{52.05},{114.25}]
How should i split it in a single value in golang ? 
For eg: 52.05
114.25

Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am new to golang and not aware of many data structures. But i figured out how to get the single value out of array of structure.

```
fmt.Println(s.Query.Results.Quote[0].LastTradePriceOnly)
```

this worked for me..I only have to iterate this in a loop to fetch all values.

Thanks.

Comment: you mentioned you were new, so note sure if you know this, but you can use: for _, q := range s.Query.Results.Quote { q.LastTradePriceOnly }  (as an easy iteration).  also, if you make LastTradePriceOnly a type float64 (or float32) it will parse in to numeric form.  don't do this if it sometimes is non-numeric

Comment: Thanks for the response David. I'll consider it :)